# Self adjusting numerical integration precision

Tags: integration, recursive-algorithms, programming, numerical-calculus

I've written a program to numerically calculate the area under a curve for a given interval and want to be able to give a precision goal.

Let $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$ be an integrable function, `quadrature(f, a, b)` the [Gauss-Legendre-Quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature), `mid(a,b)=a + 1/2 (b-a)` and `rel_error(v, w) = abs(1 - abs(v/w))` where `abs(x) = |x|`

I then calculate the area as follows:

```
  function integrate(f, a, b)
    total = quadrature(f, a, b)
    left  = quadrature(f, a, mid(a,b))
    right = quadrature(f, mid(a,b), b)

    if: rel_error(total, left+right) > epsilon
      return integrate(f, left, a, mid(a,b)) + integrate(f, right, mid(a,b), b)
    endif

    return total

  function integrate(f, total, a, b)
    left  = quadrature(f, a, mid(a, b))
    right = quadrature(f, mid(a, b), b)

    if: rel_error(total, left+right) > epsilon
      return integrate(f, left, a, mid(a,b)) + integrate(f, right, mid(a,b), b)
    endif

    return total
```

Note: I excluded some validations and a max_recursion limit for the sake of clarity.

To calculate an area I start with the top function, which may recursively call the bottom function, i.e. `integrate(x^2, 0, 10)` to approximate $\int \limits_0^{10} x^2 \mathrm{d}x$

My questions are:

Is this a solid way that will converge? How does $\epsilon$ relate to the overall precision? What value should I choose for $\epsilon$ so that `integrate(f, a, b)` differs by at most $10^{-6}$ from the exact value? You may assume $n=10$ for the quadrature.

Comment: Are you familiar with adaptive quadrature techniques?  One which my thesis advisor wrote - and we used heavily - split an integration interval into thirds and did rudimentary error estimates within each interval.  If the error is greater than some tolerance in a subinterval, then the subinterval is split into thirds and the process is recursive.

Comment: @Ron Gordon: Isn't my approach adaptive? I just don't know how to do the rudimentary error erstimate correctly. I literally guessed, this is why I'm asking here.